# Reciprocal of Beta Function

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function

We can write, using the definition of Beta function,

$\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y) = \operatorname{B}(x, y) \Gamma(x+y) $

So I was wondering if it is possible to write it the other way,
$\Gamma(x+y) =\operatorname{A}(x, y) \Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)$

where I call $\operatorname{A}(x, y)$ as the reciprocal to beta function $\operatorname{B}(x, y)$. My question is what will be the expression for $\operatorname{A}(x,y)$?

Comment: are you looking for an expression in terms of inverse Gamma function?

Comment: If you write$\Gamma(x+y) =\operatorname{A}(x, y) \Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)$, it seems that you look for the reciprocal and not the inverse.

Comment: Yes, it is reciprocal. Like beta function B(x, y) which has several integral representation. Is there any such representation for A(x, y)?

Comment: An example is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3419834).