# How to solve this integral? (with beta function and cosine)

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I need help to solve this integral, please.
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}{\cos^x(\theta)\cos(y\theta)d\theta}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be integers ? If not, I am afraid that you could fac gaussian hypergeometric functions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419834/integrals-related-to-the-reciprocal-beta-function?noredirect=1