# approximation of integral of $|\cos x|^p$

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, approximation, riemann-sum

Let $p\in [1,2)$. Let
$$
\beta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |\cos x|^p\, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{p+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1+\frac{p}{2})}.
$$
Consider the following approximation to the integral definition of $\beta$:
$$
S_n = \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \left| \cos\left(2\pi \cdot \frac{k}{2n}\right)\right|^p.
$$
We are interested in the asymptotics of the approximation error
$$
|S_n - \beta|.
$$
I have found empirically that
$$
|S_n - \beta| \leq \frac{c_p}{n^{p+1}}
$$
where $c_p$ is a constant that depends only on $p$ and $c_p\to 0$ as $p\to 2$. But I have no idea at all how to prove this. (This bound is actually tight, that is, the correct order should be $1/n^{p+1}$.)

I tried to split the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ into $2n$ pieces and sum up the approximation errors in each piece, which only gives an error of $O(1/n^2)$ instead of $O(1/n^{p+1})$. Can anyone shed some light on how to deal with the $p$-th power or how $p$ enters the exponent in the approximation error?

---

Edit: The following seems to be a proof, up to tiny boundary sloppiness that can be easily fixed.

Assume that $n$ is even and so we replace $n$ with $2n$. Note that $\cos x$ is decreasing and positive on $[0,\pi/2]$. By symmetry, it suffices to bound
\begin{align*}
E &:= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \left|\cos\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right|^p - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\cos x|^p dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\cos^p\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right) + \cos^p\left(\frac{\pi (k+1)}{2n}\right)\right) - \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2\int_{k\pi/(2n)}^{(k+1)\pi/(2n)} \cos^p xdx  \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos^p\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right) + \cos^p\left(\frac{\pi (k+1)}{2n}\right)\right) - \frac{1}{\pi/(2n)}\int_{k\pi/(2n)}^{(k+1)\pi/(2n)} \cos^p xdx\right]\\
&=: \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} E_k
\end{align*}
Recall the following mean-value result for the error of trapezoidal rule:
$$
\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx - \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} = -\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}f''(\xi)
$$

Let $f(x) = \cos^p x$, then $f'(\pi/2-\delta)\asymp \delta^{p-1}$ and $f''(\pi/2-\delta)\asymp 1/\delta^{2-p}$.

Let $\epsilon \geq 2/n$ to be determined let $K = [n\epsilon]$ so $K \geq 2$. Applying the mean-value result to the intervals corresponding to $k=0,\dots,n-K-1$, we have
$$
E = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-K-1} \frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)^2 f''(\xi_k) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n-K}^{n-1} E_k 
=: A + B.
$$
where $\xi_k \in [k\pi/(2n), (k+1)\pi/(2n)]$.

Write $A$ as
$$
A = \frac{\pi}{24n^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-K-1} f''(\xi_k)\frac{\pi}{2n} =: \frac{\pi}{24n^2} A'
$$
Note that $A'$ is the Riemann sum of $\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon} f''(x)dx$. Also note that $f''(x)$ has a unique positive root $x_0$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ and $f''(x)$ is positive and increasing when $x\geq x_0$. We can upper bound
$$
\begin{aligned}
A' &\leq \int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon} f''(x)dx + \frac{C_1}{n}\max_{x\in [0,x_0]}|f'''(x)| + \frac{C_2}{n}f''\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\right) \\
&\leq f'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\right) + \frac{C_3}{n} + \frac{C_4}{n\epsilon^{2-p}} \\
&\lesssim \epsilon^{p-1} + \frac{1}{n\epsilon^{2-p}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Next, we deal with the last term $B$. Invoke the integral estimation error from Theorem 3 of [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/10835027.pdf), which states that, if $f'$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f''\in L^\alpha(a,b)$ for some $\alpha\geq 1$, then
$$
\left|\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx - \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}\right| \leq C_\alpha (b-a)^{2-\frac{1}{\alpha}} \|f''\|_\alpha.
$$
Since $f''(\pi/2-\epsilon)\asymp 1/\epsilon^{2-p}$, $f''$ is $L^1$ integrable. It is clear that $E_k > 0$ when $k\geq n-K$, as $f''(\xi_k) > 0$  in this case. Applying the error bound above to $E_k$ ($k\geq n-K$), we obtain that
$$
B \lesssim \frac{1}{n^2}\int_{\pi/2-\epsilon}^{\pi/2} f''(x)dx \lesssim\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{x^{2-p}}dx \lesssim \frac{\epsilon^{p-1}}{n^2}.
$$
Therefore we conclude that
$$
E \lesssim \frac{\epsilon^{p-1}}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3\epsilon^{2-p}}.
$$
Taking $\epsilon = \Theta(1/n)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was only asking for $p\in [1,2)$.  For even $p$, I think you just get 0 additive error, that is, $c_p = 0$ in this case.

Comment: I am sorry : I misread it. Thanks.

Comment: @user58955 This looks like the trapezoidal rule... Look for the Euler-MacLaurin formula.

Comment: $S_n$ should be the following instead?$$S_n:=\frac\pi{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\cos^p\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$

Comment: @Tianlalu Sorry, I should have normalized $\beta$ by $1/(2\pi)$. It's now fixed.

Comment: I think the best we could get is $O(1/n)$ only, could you show us how to get $O(1/n^2)$?

Comment: @PierreCarre I think that only gives you $O(1/n^2)$ error... My main question is how to get $O(1/n^{p+1})$ error. I don't see a way to get $p$ in the exponent. It seems that one cannot use any uniform bound on the error $x^p-y^p$ or the like.

Comment: There’s no $\frac1{2n}$ in the summand before the integral. The error given by mean value theorem is $O(\frac1n)$

Comment: Now it should be $\frac n\pi$ before the integral in the summand.

Comment: @Tianlalu I normalized the integral so there is a $1/(\pi/(2n))$ before the integral. Anyway those normalization issues are minor issues, you can definitely get it right one way or the way because things need to be balanced out in the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135907/discussion-between-tianlalu-and-user58955).

Comment: @user58955 When the odd order derivatives coincide at $0$ and $2\pi$ up to the order $2p-1$, the error in the trapezoidal rule is $O(1/n^{2p})$.

Comment: @PierreCarre I don't think this is the right order... $1/n^{2p}$ is too good...

Comment: @user58955 It is correct... It is very good, but you also demand a lot on $f$. But I also noticed that this is not relevant for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "Fourier-analytic" approach, with the analysis of $n^{p+1}|S_n-\beta|$ as $n\to\infty$. Let $$
T_N(f):=\frac1N\left(\frac{f(0)+f(2\pi)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}f\Big(\frac{2k\pi}{N}\Big)\right),\\\Delta_N(f):=T_N(f)-\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,dx.$$ Suppose that $f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{inx}$ with $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|c_n|<\infty$, then $$T_N(f)=\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{2\pi ikn/N}=\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}}c_{Nd},$$ because $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi ikn/N}=0$ if $n$ is not a multiple of $N$; thus $\color{blue}{\Delta_N(f)=\sum_{d\neq 0}c_{Nd}}$. In particular, if $c_n=O(|n|^{-\alpha})$ as $n\to\pm\infty$ with $\alpha>1$, then $\Delta_N(f)=O(N^{-\alpha})$ as $N\to\infty$.

---

Take $f(x)=|\cos x|^p$ with $\color{blue}{p>0}$, then $c_n=0$ if $n$ is odd, and (see e.g. [{1}](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12#E5) or [{2}](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3419834)) $$c_{2n}=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^p x\cos 2nx\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{2^p\Gamma(p/2+1+n)\Gamma(p/2+1-n)},$$ so that, using the reflection formula for $\Gamma$ and that $\Gamma(x+a)/x^a\Gamma(x)\to1$ as $x\to\infty$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^{p+1}c_{2n}=\lambda_p:=\frac1{2^p\pi}\Gamma(p+1)\sin\frac{p\pi}{2}.$$

Now, denoting $a_n:=n^{p+1}(S_n-\beta)=n^{p+1}\Delta_{2n}(f)$, we get easily $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=-2\lambda_p\zeta(p+1)=2\pi^p\zeta(-p);\\\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}=-(1-2^{-p})\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the Fourier-analytic approach! This is something I was looking for.