# Ramanujan 1920 paper ; question on some definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform, gamma-function, beta-function

At the beginning of his paper Ramanujan makes the following statement:

> It is well known that,
> $$ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \cos x \right)^m e^{inx} dx
>  = \frac{\pi}{2^m} 
>  \frac{\Gamma(1+m)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{m+n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{m-n}{2}\right)} $$
> if $\Re[m]>-1$.

Unfortunately I do not know that. Can someone explain how the l.h.s. produces the r.h.s. (or give a reference that explains this)?

Then Ramanujan makes another statement:

> It follows from this and Fourier's theorem that, if $n$ is any real number except $\pm \pi$ and $\Re[\alpha + \beta]>1$, or if $n=\pm \pi$ and $\Re[\alpha+\beta]>2$ then
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inx}}{\Gamma(\alpha+x)\Gamma(\beta-x)}
> = \frac{\left(2 \cos\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\right)^{\alpha+\beta-2}}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta-1)} e^{\frac{in(\beta-\alpha)}{2}}\quad \mathrm{or} \quad 0,
> $$
> according as $\vert n \vert < \pi$ or $\vert n \vert \geq \pi$.

This is another statement that is not trivial for me. It would be great if someone could provide proof or a reference.

Comment: They are not trivial for most of the people

Comment: The paper in question is available at http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram27.html

Comment: $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \cos x \right)^m e^{inx} dx=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \cos x \right)^m \cos (nx) dx$$
the evaluation is here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419834/integrals-related-to-the-reciprocal-beta-function?noredirect=1

Comment: Sorry @Svyatoslav, I cannot follow the proof in the link and also I do not think he is looking at the integral you wrote.

Comment: The method in the link is applicable to this integral as well. You can find other solutions here - https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D%5Ccos%5Em(x)%5Ccos(nx)dx%24&p=1