# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin^a (x) dx$, $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

> I want to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin^a (x)\, dx$$ where $a>0$ is a real number.

I tried: $$I(a)= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin^a(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x^a\,dx$$
$$ I(a)=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{4^m}{2m\left(2m+a\right)\binom{2m}{m}}$$
$$I(a)=\frac{1}{a+2}\cdot\phantom{}_3 F_2\left(1,1,1+\tfrac{a}{2};\tfrac{3}{2},2+\tfrac{a}{2};1\right)$$
Any other method please.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
*edit* The series expansion of $ \arcsin(x)^2$ is
$$2\;\arcsin(x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$$
Differentiating the above series we get the formula used in the question.

Comment: Oops, I thought it said $2\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$

Comment: [According to wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x+sin%5Ee%28x%29+dx), the indefinite integral is $\frac14 \sin^{1 + a}(x)\left(\frac{4 x \cos(x) \phantom{}_2 F_1\left(1, \frac{2 + a}2, \frac{3 + a}2, \sin^2(x)\right)}{1 + a} - \frac{2^{-a} \sqrt\pi\ \Gamma(1 + a) \sin(x) \phantom{}_3 F_2\left(1, 1 + \frac a2, 1 + \frac a2;\frac{3+a}2, 2 +\frac  a2;\sin^2(x)\right)}{\Gamma(\frac{3 + a}2) \Gamma(\frac{4 + a}2)}\right)$, But I do not know how to calculate it myself.

Comment: For $a=\frac12$ in [first](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x+sqrt%28sin%28x%29%29+dx+from+0+to+pi%2F2) and in [second](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+asin+x%2Fsrqt%281-x%5E2%29+sqrt%28x%29+dx+from+0+to+1) formula wolfram finds value $\frac13 \left(\frac{\pi^{\frac32} \Gamma(\frac74)}{\Gamma(\frac54)} - 2 \phantom{}_3 F_2(\frac12, \frac12, 1;\frac32, \frac74 ;1)\right)\approx1.09749$

Comment: From line $2$ to $3$ is a huge leap. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake?

Comment: @K.defaoite I think it is correct. Please see this:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+4%5Em%2F%282+m%282+m%2Bn%29+%282m%29+choose+%28m%29%29%2C+m%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: @Max You should add the power series you used for $\arcsin(x)/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Look at the edit for using WA and generating the coefficients.

Comment: Did you try with WA what I wrote in the edit ?

Comment: @Max I am curious about the application for your questions involving $\sin^a x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary (enough) deduction of the (already mentioned) equality $$\boxed{I(a)=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{4}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}2\right)}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(a+2k)^2}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n}(a+k)}.\quad(\Re a>-1)}$$

We note that $$(a+1)\big(I(a)-I(a+2)\big)=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos x\,(\sin^{a+1}x)'\,dx$$ and integrate by parts; this yields the recurrence $$I(a)=\frac{a+2}{a+1}I(a+2)-\frac1{(a+1)(a+2)}.$$

Reusing it with $a+2$ in place of $a$, we get $$I(a)=\frac{(a+2)(a+4)}{(a+1)(a+3)}I(a+4)-\frac1{(a+1)(a+2)}-\frac{a+2}{(a+1)(a+3)(a+4)}$$ and then, by induction (I'm writing it expanded intentionally),
\begin{align}
I(a)&=\frac{(a+2)(a+4)\cdots(a+2n)}{(a+1)(a+3)\cdots(a+2n-1)}I(a+2n)
\\&-\frac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)}-\frac{a+2}{(a+1)(a+3)(a+4)}
\\&-\dots-\frac{(a+2)(a+4)\cdots(a+2n-2)}{(a+1)(a+3)\cdots(a+2n-1)(a+2n)}.
\end{align}

**And now we take $n\to\infty$.** The fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a+2)(a+4)\cdots(a+2n)}{(a+1)(a+3)\cdots(a+2n-1)}\frac1{\sqrt n}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}2\right)}$$ may be obtained using [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler%27s_definition_as_an_infinite_product) representations of $\Gamma$, or just the known limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(x+a)}{x^a\,\Gamma(x)}=1.$$

And [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) gives the remaining piece: $$\lim_{a\to\infty}I(a)\sqrt{a}=(\pi/2)^{3/2}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}I(a+2n)\sqrt{n}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}4.$$

Comment: Sure, It will be the right place indeed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a very nice solution, for sure.

Comment: Please explain how by using Laplace's method we get $$\lim_{a\to\infty}I(a)\sqrt{a}=(\pi/2)^{3/2}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}I(a+2n)\sqrt{n}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}4.$$ Pardon me, I tried a lot but could not prove this limit.

Comment: @Max: the method gives the asymptotics of $\int f(x)e^{ag(x)}\,dx$ as $a\to\infty$, and the linked Wiki page covers the case when $g(x)$ has a single maximum at an interior point of the integration range. In our case $g(x)=\log\sin x$ has the maximum at $x_0=\pi/2$, i.e. a *boundary* point. This case is not covered in Wiki, but the answer is just half the answer in the interior-point case. In case you didn't study (and/or practice) the method... (TBC)

Comment: @Max: ... an elementary way: substitute $x=\pi/2-t/\sqrt{a}$ in the definition of $I(a)$ to get $$I(a)\sqrt{a}=\int_0^{\pi\sqrt{a}/2}\left(\frac\pi2-\frac{t}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\cos^a\frac{t}{\sqrt{a}}\,dt,$$ and take $a\to\infty$ using [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). A suitable dominating function comes from $$\cos^a\frac{t}{\sqrt a}\leqslant\left(1-\frac{4t^2}{a\pi^2}\right)^a\leqslant e^{-4t^2/\pi^2},$$ and the result is $$\lim_{a\to\infty}I(a)\sqrt{a}=\frac\pi2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt=\text{(expected)}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}x^{2 n+1}$$ Assuming $a>0$
$$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x^a\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{(2 n+2+a) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
$$I(a)=\frac 1{a+2} \,\,\,
   _3F_2\left(1,1,\frac{a+2}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{a+4}{2};1\right
   )$$ which is the same (numerically check) as
$$\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{4
   \Gamma \left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)}-\frac{\pi   \Gamma (a+1)}{2^{(a+2)}\,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{a+3}{2}\right)^2}\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{a+2}{2};
   \frac{a+3}{2},\frac{a+3}{2};1\right)$$ given by Mathematica for the original integral.

**Edit**

I do not see how to expand the result for small values of $a$. But, back to
$$x \sin^a(x)=x^{a+1}\,\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^a$$
$$\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^a=1-\frac{a }{6}x^2+\frac{a (5 a-2)}{360}  x^4-\frac{a \left(35 a^2-42 a+16\right) }{45360}x^6+O(x^8)$$ the integration is simple.

Expanded as a series
$$I(a)=\, \frac{\pi ^{a+2}}{2^{(a+12)} }\left( 512-\frac{2 \left(362880+15120 \pi ^2+84 \pi ^4+\pi ^6\right)
   }{2835}a+O\left(a^2\right) \right)$$ which is not bad for
$0<a <0.05$ as show below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact value}\\
 0.00 & 1.23370 & 1.23370 \\
 0.01 & 1.23038 & 1.23042 \\
 0.02 & 1.22701 & 1.22717 \\
 0.03 & 1.22358 & 1.22395 \\
 0.04 & 1.22010 & 1.22075 \\
 0.05 & 1.21656 & 1.21758 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The next term in the expansion is
$$\frac{725760+15120 \pi ^2+896 \pi ^4+11 \pi ^6}{5670}a^2$$ which improves signifiantly
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact value}\\
 0.00 & 1.23370 & 1.23370 \\
 0.01 & 1.23043 & 1.23042 \\
 0.02 & 1.22718 & 1.22717 \\
 0.03 & 1.22396 & 1.22395 \\
 0.04 & 1.22077 & 1.22075 \\
 0.05 & 1.21762 & 1.21758 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Computing the values of the required derivatives of the generalized hypergeometric function, making them rational,
$$I(a)=\frac 1{2+a} \left( \frac{\pi ^2}{4}+\frac{692 }{1203}a-\frac{32 }{645}a^2+\frac{9
   }{1072}a^3+O\left(a^4\right)\right)$$ which is quite good up to $a=1$

**Edit**

Type in Wolfram Alpha

`Rationalize[N[SeriesCoefficient[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 + a/2}, {3/2, 2 + a/2}, 1],{a,0,1}],20],10^(-6)]`

you will obtain the $\frac{692 }{1203}$.

**Update**  *(after @metamorphy's elegant answer)*

Assuming that $a$ is an integer, the recurrence relation given by @metamorphy

$$I_a=\frac{a+2}{a+1}I_{a+2}-\frac1{(a+1)(a+2)}$$ has explicit solution
$$I_{2a}=\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 \Gamma
   (a+1)}-\frac{\,
   _3F_2\left(1,a+1,a+1;a+\frac{3}{2},a+2;1\right)}{2 (a+1) (2 a+1)}$$
$$I_{2a+1}=\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \Gamma (a+1)}{4 \Gamma
   \left(a+\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\frac{\,
   _3F_2\left(1,a+\frac{3}{2},a+\frac{3}{2};a+2,a+\frac{5}{2};1\right)}{2 (a+1) (2 a+3)}$$ For both cases, the first term is asymptotic to
$$\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{4 \sqrt{a}}$$ as @metamorphy already showed.

Comment: Are you saying that the last and second last expression are the same?

Comment: @Max. As I wrote, this has been checked numerically (not a proof)

Comment: Can we further simplify what we have in your answer $I(a)=\frac 1{a+2} \,\,\,
   _3F_2\left(1,1,\frac{a+2}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{a+4}{2};1\right
   )$

Comment: @Max. I do not think **I** could  (but who knows ?).

Comment: @Max. I think that we can. I am working it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do we get the following?$$I(a)=\, \frac{\pi ^{a+2}}{2^{(a+12)} }\left( 512-\frac{2 \left(362880+15120 \pi ^2+84 \pi ^4+\pi ^6\right)
   }{2835}a+O\left(a^2\right) \right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit. +1 for it. I would  really appreciate if you could please show mathematically that how did you get $\frac{692}{1203}$ by using derivatives of generalised hypergeometric function. I will be obliged to accept your answer.

Comment: @Max. Don't feel obliged to anything. As I wrote, I computed with high accuracy the derivatives of the generalised hypergeometric function and then I made them rational; that's all.

Comment: Thanks. But then can you please give me an idea on how to evaluate the derivative of generalised hypergeometric function. Atleast for the $\frac{692}{1203}$ part. I would really appreciate if you give me a link for the computation of this number or its approximation

Comment: Thank you. But then how can we have a closed form for coeffecient of a? Please help me with this.

Comment: @Max: The value $\frac{692}{1203}\approx 0.575228\color{red}{595178719867−}$
 is a rational approximation of the exact value
$$2I'(0)+I(0)=\frac{\pi^2}8(1−2\log2)+\frac78\zeta(3)\approx 0.575228\color{blue}{22443653569+}.$$

Comment: It wouldn't be a Claude Leibovici answer without a table comparing exact values and approximations!

Answer (score 2):

Another idea leads to a different formula (still for $\Re a>-1$): $$\boxed{I(a)=2^{-a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{a}{n}\frac1{(2n-a)^2}-\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{4}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}2\right)}\cot^2\frac{a\pi}2}$$ (interpreted as a limit if $a$ is an even integer). It is based on the fact that $$I(a)=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^a x\sin bx\,dx\right|_{b=0},$$ and the approach I've taken [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3419923).

This approach might also be followed directly. Assume (temporarily) $\color{blue}{-1<\Re a<0}$. Consider $f(z)=z^{-a-1}(1-z^2)^a\log z$ (principal values everywhere) and the contours $\gamma_+$, $\gamma_-$ from the linked answer. Then, manipulating $0=\int_{\gamma_\pm}f(z)\,dz$ the same way, we obtain
\begin{align}
2^a I(a)&=J_-(a)\cos\frac{a\pi}2-J_+(a),
\\J_\pm(a)&=\int_0^1 x^{-a-1}(1\pm x^2)^a\log x\,dx.
\end{align}

Now $J_-(a)$ reduces to $$\int_0^1 t^{\lambda-1}(1-t)^{\mu-1}\log t\,dt=\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\mathrm{B}(\lambda,\mu)=\mathrm{B}(\lambda,\mu)\big(\psi(\lambda)-\psi(\lambda+\mu)\big)$$ at $\mu=a+1$ and $\lambda=-a/2$; with the [reflection formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for $\Gamma$ and $\psi$, this yields the gamma quotient term in the formula stated at the beginning. And, using the binomial expansion, $$J_+(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{a}{n}\int_0^1 x^{2n-a-1}\log x\,dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{a}{n}\frac1{(2n-a)^2}$$ gives the remaining piece. Finally, the result holds for $\Re a>-1$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: Clean up done. Thanks a lot

Comment: I doubt that your formula in "this above" answer is correct. Please see and make the changes. With regards.

Comment: The integral $I(a)$ is becoming undefined for some values of $a$ such that $\Re(a)>-1$

Comment: @Max: Not following. The integral $I(a)$ is defined (in your question) for all $a$ s.t. $\Re a>-1$. The formula stated in the answer takes the "$\infty-\infty$" indeterminate form if $a$ is an even (nonnegative) integer, and that's precisely why the "(interpreted as a limit if...)" remark is made above. (BTW, I've checked it numerically, like I always do in non-trivial cases.)

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add a separate answer.*

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652051/series-expansion-of-left-frac-sin-xx-righta-at-x-0/4652086#4652086), @Aaron Hendrickson gave the complete expansion
$$\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^a=\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_m x^{2m}$$ where $c_0=1$ and
$$c_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k\,\frac{k(a+1)-m}{(2k+1)!}\,c_{m-k}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2} x\sin^a (x)\, dx=\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_m \int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2} x^{2 m+a+1}= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac {c_m}{a+2 (m+1) } \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{a+2 (m+1)}$$

Comment: +1 for this answer.

Comment: Please simplify the $c_m$ a little bit. Is there a closed form for $c_m$?

Comment: @Max No way and no. Look at the link post for almost the same question from .... yourself ! This form (tanks Aaron !) is really nice. Cheers :-)

Comment: Okay. Thank you again.