# Series expansion with nth term of $\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^a$

Tags: trigonometry

> Using Mathematica, I need an expansion with $n$th term of $$ f(x)=\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^a   $$ about $x=0$ where $a\geq 0$ or if $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{2n }x^{2n}$$ then I need a formula for $b_{2n}$   .

By wolfram alpha (see:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+%28%28sin+x%29%2Fx%29%5Ea+at+x%3D0) we have $$f(x)=1-\frac{a}{6}x^2+\frac{a (5 a-2)}{360}  x^4-\frac{a \left(35 a^2-42 a+16\right) }{45360}x^6+O(x^8)$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The question is??? You don't believe the result?

Comment: No, I believe the result. Question is the nth term of the expansion.

Comment: `Series[(Sin[x]/x)^a, {x, 0, 6}] // Normal // Map[Factor]` ?

Comment: @Max Coefficient for variable `n` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I mean if $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{2n }x^{2n}$$ then I need a formula for $b_{2n}$

Comment: @Syed So using this code will we get the nth term of series expansion of $f(x)$ about $x=0$?

Comment: What is known about `a`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann $a$ is a non negative real number.

Comment: Maple's best is $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left( {\frac {27\,{{\rm e}^{k\ln  \left( 3
 \right) }}\cos \left( 1/2\,k\pi \right) }{4\, \left( k+3 \right) !}}-
3/4\,{\frac {\cos \left( 1/2\,k\pi \right) }{ \left( k+3 \right) !}}
 \right) {x}^{k}
 $$ for $a=3$ by `convert((sin(x)/x)^3, FPS)`. Maple fails with $a=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

Answering [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652051/series-expansion-of-left-frac-sin-xx-righta-at-x-0/4652086#4652086) on Mathematics Stack Excahane, @Aaron Hendrickson provided what I would consider as the only viable solution

$$c_m(a)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m(ka-m+k)\,\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\,c_{m-k}(a)$$ with $c_0(a)=1$.

May be, for a given value of $a$, something could be done but for general $a$ this could just be a dream.

Comment: @user64494. Being blind, it is extremely difficult to write in comments.

Comment: I don't think so.  You may type your comment in any  editor, making use of glasses, and then copy&paste.