# General expansion of $\cos^m(x)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

The question is how to prove
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos^m(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2^{m-1}} \left(  \sum_{r=0}^{2r<m}  { m \choose r }  \cos (m-2r)x        \right)  +  \frac{1}{2^{m}} {m \choose \frac{m}{2}}
& m=2,4,\cdots ,  \\
\frac{1}{2^{m-1}} \left(  \sum_{r=0}^{2r<m}  { m \choose r }  \cos (m-2r)x        \right) 
& m=1,3,\cdots , \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}

that presented in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

This is my try:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos^m(x)&=&\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^m=2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom {m}{k} e^{kix} 
e^{-(m-k)ix}\\ &=& 2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom {m}{k} e^{kix-mix+kix} 
\\ &=& 2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom {m}{k} e^{(2k-m)ix} 
\\ &=& 2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom {m}{k} \left\{\cos((2k-m)x)+i\sin((2k-m)x)\right\}
\\ &=& 2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom {m}{k} \left\{\cos((m-2k)x)-i\sin((m-2k)x)\right\}
\\ &=& 2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x)
\end{eqnarray*}

If m is even:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos^m(x)&=&
 2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x) \\ &=&
2^{-m}\sum_{k\neq \frac{m}{2}} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x)+ 2^{-m}\binom {m}{m/2} \\ &=&
2^{-m}\sum_{2k< m} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x)+
2^{-m}\sum_{2k>m} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x)+
 2^{-m}\binom {m}{m/2} \\ &=&
2\times2^{-m}\sum_{2k< m} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x)+
2^{-m}\binom {m}{m/2} \\ &=&
\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum_{2k< m} \binom {m}{k} \cos((m-2k)x)+
\frac{1}{2^{m}}\binom {m}{m/2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Try substituting $j=m-k$ in the second to last sum

Comment: You've lost all your $x$s on the last two lines

Comment: The last sum must equal a real number, so maybe the imaginary parts cancel out pairwise. If they do, see what happens to the real parts for each of those pairs.

Comment: I think there are multiple similar questions asked in the past . You should consider those for help .

Comment: The formulas after "how to prove" are wrong: the binomial coefficient should be ${m\choose r}.$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4662511/1103878) is a very similar question that might interest you with an answer to this.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc, Thanks.